# Optimizing a lua table backup

Tags: arrays, optimization, lua, lua-table

I am trying to create a speedy Sudoku solver and in one of the steps I need to save the state of the puzzle. I started off by using various deep copy functions to do this, but found it quite slow. In the end I came up with these two functions but luatrace shows these two functions still taking up a significant amount of time.

Is there anything that can be done to optimize this or is time to write it in C?

```
local function backupCells(cells)
    local serial = {{}, {}}
    for i = 1, #cells do
        serial[1][i] = {unpack(cells[i].domain)}
        serial[2][i] = cells[i].value
    end
    return serial
end

local function restoreCells(cells, serial)
    for i=1, #cells do
        cells[i].domain = serial[1][i]
        cells[i].value = serial[2][i]
    end
end
```

**Update: (additional info was requested!)**

So, each cell in  `cells` represents a square on the sudoku grid. The `value` property is set once the value of the cell has been determined (otherwise it's `nil`). The `domain` is a table of all possible values. Between the calls to `backupCells` and `restoreCells` forward checking is completed and the values/domains of cells change quite a bit - `serial` does not incur any such change.

In general the restore is an "undo" so that the solver can guess at another value and forward check from there.

Comment: I'm not really sure why they are written as they are, for any useful answer the exact layout of `cells` (with semantics and rationale) are needed. Also of interest, what can happen to `cells` between the calls, and what might happen to `serial`.

Comment: I've updated the post to include some additional info about the sudoku solver!

Answer (score 0):

My advice:
Simplify your cell-layout.

Every cell is always a table containing all possible values, thus:

- If `not t[1]`, we obviously made an error.
- Otherwise, if `not t[2]`, `t[1]` is the value of the cell.
- Otherwise, `t` contains multiple possibilities.

Thus, you can copy a board like this:

```
local function cloneBoard(cells)
    local r = {}
    for i = 1, #cells do
        -- Option 1
        local t, cell = {}, cells[i]
        r[i] = t
        for j = 1, #cell, 1 do
            t[j] = cell[j]
        end
        -- Option 2
        r[i] = {unpack(cells[i])}
        -- Measure which option is faster for you
    end
    return r
end
```

Next, you throw away the old board, just use (a clone of) the saved board.